# music visualization with webgl and three.js

Tags: three.js, web-audio-api

Can you help me?  I try to make music visualization http://webmaster9.ru/freelance/mysicusa/ it based on http://iacopoapps.appspot.com/hopalongwebgl/
 I have signal (level of music) but cant change visual effects according music. It use

```js
var materials = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { size: (3 ), map: sprite1, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, depthTest: false, transparent : true } );
materials.color.setHSV(hueValues[s], DEF_SATURATION, DEF_BRIGHTNESS);

var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, materials );
particles.myMaterial = materials;
```

1 Can I change  opacity or brightness according music?  Probably using controls? can you show me examples?
2 Can I change  texture according music?
2 Can I add light and change light   according music? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can get the generated audio data from DOM and use in WebGL javascript part to handle values or even use THREE.js to handle those values.

Just take a look how [web-audio](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/?redirect_from_locale=pt) works

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer. I don't have problems with music? I use soundmanager2 it works for me. But I need to change  Particle system in three.js  according music signal. Probably I must use controls with  Particle system. Do you articls or examples controls +  Particle system?

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2011/09/21/music-colour-particles/) can help, is an API developed by [zz95](https://github.com/zz85)